# beforeFilter() not being called?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have added a function to check for language parameter to my AppController

```
function beforeFilter(){
    if(Configure::read('Config.language') == 'ara'){
         $this->layout = 'rtl-layout';
    } else {
        $this->layout = 'ltr-layout';
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work in my other controllers ?

```
class ImagesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Images';
    var $helpers = array('TinyMCE');

    function beforeFilter(){
        if(!isset($this->params['admin'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access denied.', true));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>false));
            exit();
        }    
    }

    function index() {
        $this->Image->recursive = 1;
        $this->set('images', $this->paginate());
    }

}
```

Please help me, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: is there a reason you use beforeFilter()? because it will not be invoked on errors and therefore those will probably end up with the wrong layout... use beforeRender() if you want to avoid this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forgot to call the base class' `beforeFilter()` since I was overloading it in my `ImagesController`

```
class ImagesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Images';
    var $helpers = array('TinyMCE');

    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter(); // <-- here
        if(!isset($this->params['admin'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access denied.', true));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>false));
            exit();
        }    
    }

    function index() {
        $this->Image->recursive = 1;
        $this->set('images', $this->paginate());
    }

}
```

Comment: Ha thats priceless! ( princeless? )